# OAuth in Angular 9

Tags: angular, oauth

I'm trying implement OAuth in Angular 9, but when I send the post request to URL that will generate the token I recept error 401 because I need a first authorization to do this, but I don't now how implement the autorizathion request.

the auth.service.ts

```
  // Sign-in
  signIn(user: User) {
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post('https://credbem-app.herokuapp.com/oauth/token', user)
      .subscribe(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token)
      });
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  }
```

the authconfig.interceptor.ts

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken
            }
        });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the header at login request like If you are using oauth2

```
const headers = {
  Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('clientId:secret'),
  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
};
```

and then send a requst with

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl, user, {headers});
```

if you are using simple jwt 
Then it can be CORS issue which can be resolved by using proxy-config.